# How can I add multiple UI children to a CustomControl's DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

I've created a CustomControl that represents a tile. It contains a header with a title, a toolbar and the main content and is working fine. However, I want to move the `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` to the control's template, as I always want the toolbar to be presented like this.

As I want to add the children to a `DependencyProperty` and not directly to the control, I can't derive from `ItemsControl`. Can I solve this without adding a lot of boilerplate code to my control?

I assume that I have to replace the second `ContentPresenter` with an `ItemsPresenter`, but:

- What type does the ToolbarContent `DependencyProperty` need to be? Neither `UIElementCollection` nor `ItemsCollection` can be instanciated.
- How can I tell the ItemsPresenter to display its content in an horizontal `StackPanel`?

**Current Usage:**

```
<controls:Tile Title="Projects" Margin="6,6,0,6">
    <controls:Tile.ToolbarContent>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:ToolbarButton Text="Add" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;Component/Resources/plus-16.png" />
            <controls:ToolbarButton Text="Remove" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;Component/Resources/delete-16.png" />
            <controls:ToolbarButton ... />
            <controls:ToolbarButton ... />
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:Tile.ToolbarContent>
    <ListView x:Name="MainContent" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" />
</controls:Tile>
```

**Requested Usage:**

```
<controls:Tile Title="Projects" Margin="6,6,0,6">
    <controls:Tile.ToolbarContent>
        <controls:ToolbarButton Text="Add" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;Component/Resources/plus-16.png" />
        <controls:ToolbarButton Text="Remove" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;Component/Resources/delete-16.png" />
        <controls:ToolbarButton ... />
        <controls:ToolbarButton ... />
    </controls:Tile.ToolbarContent>
    <ListView x:Name="MainContent" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" />
</controls:Tile>
```

**Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="controls:Tile">
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor_100}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Tile">
                <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor_40}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Margin="3" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Foreground="White" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="1" Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor_40}" Padding="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ToolbarContent" Content="{TemplateBinding ToolbarContent}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Row="2" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Code:**

```
public class Tile : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ToolbarContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata());

    public FrameworkElement ToolbarContent
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ToolbarContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToolbarContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    static Tile()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Tile), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Tile)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good way to do literally what you are asking for. You're overloading the `ContentControl` type in a way that IMHO looks clumsy and not really in keeping with the intended design of that particular control. That said, it is possible to get something along those lines to work.

The important thing to understand is that you're not going to be able to create a collection that you then assign to the `StackPanel` children. That's not how `Panel` objects work. Instead, you need some other control that you can assign a collection of controls to and have that work. The usual control for this purpose is an `ItemsControl` object.

You can make your `ToolbarContent` property an `ObservableCollection<UIElement>`, and then bind its value to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property. Within the `ItemsControl`, you can set the `ItemsPanel` property to have the `ItemsControl` use a `StackPanel` with your desired layout (e.g. `Orientation="Horizontal"`).

For example:

```
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:Tile">
        <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor_40}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
              <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Margin="3" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Foreground="White" />
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="1" Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor_40}" Padding="1">
              <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ToolbarContent}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Row="2" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
```

And:

```
class Tile : ContentControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ToolbarContentKey =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ToolbarContent", typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarContentProperty = ToolbarContentKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Tile), new PropertyMetadata());

    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> ToolbarContent
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ToolbarContentProperty); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public Tile()
    {
        SetValue(ToolbarContentKey, new ObservableCollection<UIElement>());
    }
}
```

Then when you use the syntax you desire, the elements will be added to the collection and that collection bound to the `ItemsSource` property so that they can be displayed using the `StackPanel` as the host.

Now, while that will work, to me the template you're defining really has more of a "composite control" feel to it. And that generally means implementing a `UserControl`. With a `UserControl`, you are just declaring a control that is itself made up of a collection of other controls, with the layout and other characteristics defined in XAML similar to the way is done for a `Window`.

In this approach, instead of creating an outer collection and binding to the property of an inner element, you can expose the inner element's collection as part of the public interface of the `UserControl` and add things to it directly. This also would allow you to define the layout/composition of the custom control in a more direct way (e.g. having an actual `StackPanel` element rather than having to wrap it in an `ItemsControl`).

That might look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO37929673CollectionContent.Tile2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="root"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
          Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=root}"
          UseLayoutRounding="{Binding UseLayoutRounding, ElementName=root}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="{Binding SnapsToDevicePixels, ElementName=root}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Border x:Name="Header" Background="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=root}">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=root}"
                   Margin="3"
                   Text="{Binding Title, ElementName=root}" Foreground="White" />
      </Border>
      <Border x:Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" Padding="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </Border>
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent, ElementName=root}" Grid.Row="2" />
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And:

```
[ContentPropertyAttribute("MainContent")]
public partial class Tile2 : UserControl
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ToolbarContentKey =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ToolbarContent", typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(Tile2), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolbarContentProperty = ToolbarContentKey.DependencyProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(Tile2), new PropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(object), typeof(Tile2));

    public UIElementCollection ToolbarContent
    {
        get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ToolbarContentProperty); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public object MainContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public Tile2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetValue(ToolbarContentKey, stackPanel1.Children);
    }
}
```

The usage syntax is the same (i.e. exactly what you ask for in your post) and you can style the control in the same way as well. But it encapsulates the layout for the control in the `UserControl` definition itself, rather than relying on a `ControlTemplate` assigned in a style to do that.

Note that `UserControl` is itself a `ContentControl` subclass. So if there are features of `ContentControl` that you felt are important to use, you can still take advantage of them. It's just that the `UserControl` paradigm IMHO makes the relationship of the client and custom control clearer and easier to maintain.